# Using id (Primary Key) of a Model as ForeignKey when creating new model instances in Django through shell

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

For illustration purposes, just two plain models:

```
class PrimaryModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class SecondaryModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryModel)
```

Now trying to create instances in shell:

```
>>> import testapp.models
>>> a=testapp.models.PrimaryModel(foo="Test1")
>>> a.save()
>>> b=testapp.models.SecondaryModel(bar=1)
```

... and of course the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 405, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/home/pkaramol/Workspace/django-env/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 337, in __set__
    self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "SecondaryModel.bar" must be a "PrimaryModel" instance.
```

The question is why can't we use the id of the PrimaryModel (as in the erroneous example above) and we have to use an instance?
Have also tried to use the `to_field` field as in

```
class SecondaryModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryModel, to_field='foo')
```

but that did not change the situation.

Comment: From Django tutorial: "By convention, Django appends "_id" to the foreign key field name. (Yes, you can override this, as well.)". https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use id of a PrimaryModel you should do it like this:

```
b=testapp.models.SecondaryModel(bar_id=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

```
>>> import testapp.models
>>> a=testapp.models.PrimaryModel(foo="Test1")
>>> a.save()
>>> b=testapp.models.SecondaryModel()
>>> b.bar_id = 1
>>> b.save()
```

Actually you can access fk id by just adding _id to the foreignkey name. Just create the model and then set the fk_id manually then save